# Unexpected results running chrome.tabs.executeScript() in my Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting a somewhat unexpected result from running the following script (in my Chrome Extension):

```
        chrome.windows.getAll({populate: true}, function(wnds)
        {
            for(var w = 0; w < wnds.length; w++)
            {
                var tabs = wnds[w].tabs;

                for(var t = 0; t < tabs.length; t++)
                {
                    var tab = tabs[t];
                    var tabUrl = tab.url;

                    try
                    {
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                            file: "content.js",
                            allFrames: true,
                            matchAboutBlank: true
                        }, function(arrRes)
                        {
                            if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
                            {
                                console.error("INJ ERR: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log("INJ OK: " + tabUrl);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

when the script runs by itself I get the following in the console log screen:

[image]

but when I step through it with a debugger, it outputs something like this (or correct info for each page):

[image]

I'm obviously expecting the second result. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a closure for each invocation of `executeScript` so you get the right value of `tabUrl` each time your callback function is invoked. The way your code is right now, all invocations will use the last value of `tabUrl`. One way to fix that would be:

```
    chrome.windows.getAll({populate: true}, function(wnds)
    {
        for(var w = 0; w < wnds.length; w++)
        {
            var tabs = wnds[w].tabs;

            for(var t = 0; t < tabs.length; t++)
            (function()
            {
                var tab = tabs[t];
                var tabUrl = tab.url;

                try
                {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                        file: "content.js"
                    }, function(arrRes)
                    {
                        if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
                        {
                            console.error("INJ ERR: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log("INJ OK: " + tabUrl);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                }
            })();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh, shoot. Forgot about those closures. Thanks.