# How to avoid "Extension context invalidated" errors when messaging AFTER an Extension update?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a smooth experience for users of my Chrome Extension after I release updates.

I reinject my content script on an update of the app, and my functionality works even if the user continues to use my Extension on a page that has NOT been refreshed after the Extension update. Refreshing the page is ideal, but I don't want to have to force that on my users.

However, I get the following errors in my content script console (the page the content script is inserted into) AFTER the Extension updates but BEFORE the page is refreshed when my code attempts to message from the content script/page to my background page:

> Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated.

Is there a way to 'rebuild' the connection? I've tried a long-lived port and regular messaging - updating the Extension has the same effect.

Any ideas/direction appreciated.

Here is my simple messaging code (in the content script) that throws the error...but IS able to communicate with the background script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "recordFeedback", obj: commentObj, source: source}, function(response){
  console.log('Sent to DB...response was: ', response, response.recordFeedbackResponse);
});
```

Comment: Simply [reinsert the content scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11598753/). The only complication is when your content script has DOM listeners in which case you'll need to tell it to disconnect them via [another DOM message](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/blob/0c8e69fb/content/install-hook-openusercss.js#L149-L168).

Comment: Thank you for taking a look...and the link. I tried the "var reconnectToExtension = function () {" approach in that article and get the same thing. I can't find any documentation for the error "Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated." Basically my content script, even though reinjected, can talk to the background page but throw that error...which is worrisome.

Comment: With my approach you don't need that excessive reconnectToExtension hack.

Comment: Don't get it. Your aproach "reinsert the content scripts" has reconnectToExtension hack, or you have another approach?

Comment: I faced this error while during development, when I forgot to reload the tab after making a change and building the code. So simply reloading the tab removed this error.

Answer (score 69):

When an extension is unloaded, the existing content scripts lose their connection to the rest of the extension—i.e. ports close, and they would be unable to use `runtime.sendMessage()`—but the content scripts themselves still continue to work, as they're already injected into their pages.

It's the same when an extension is reloaded: those existing content scripts will still be there, but unable to send messages; attempts to do so cause errors like the one you're encountering. Further, as it's common for extensions to inject their content scripts into existing tabs when they are loaded (on Chrome—Firefox does that automatically), you'll end up with more than one copy of the content script running in a given tab: the original, now-disconnected one, and the current, connected one.

Problems can arise if either: (1) your original content script is still trying to communicate with the rest of the extension or (2) your original content script does things like modify the DOM, as you could end up with those changes done more than once.

**That's probably why you're still getting the error even after re-injecting your content scripts: the error is coming from the original content script that's still there, but disconnected.**

*This has paraphrased [some helpful background information that I found when previously researching this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30529003/1485308). Note that Firefox automatically unloads content scripts (more on that later).*

## Solutions

If you are not automatically re-injecting your content scripts, then you can [try to get the existing script to reconnect on upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11598753/), as per [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)'s comment above.

Here's some further info and advice, particularly useful if you inject new content scripts and want to [disable the original, disconnected, one when a new one is injected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25844023/1485308).

Regardless of whether you would like to try to reconnect using the existing content script, or stop the original content script from making further changes and inject a new one, you need to detect that an unload has occurred. You can use the port's `disconnect` handler to catch when your extension is unloaded. If your extension only uses simple one-time message passing, and not ports, then that code is as simple as running the following when your content script starts up (I first saw this technique in some code from [lydell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2010616/lydell)).

```
browser.runtime.connect().onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
    // clean up when content script gets disconnected
})
```

[On Firefox, the port's `disconnect` is not fired](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1223425), because the content scripts are removed before they would receive it. This has the advantage that this detection isn't necessary (nor is manual content script injection, as content scripts are injected automatically too), but it does mean that there's no opportunity to reset any changes made to the DOM by your content script when it was running.

Comment: I run into getting `Chrome Extension message passing: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist`
It turns out you have to open a listener in your background script first.
Putting this in your background script solves it:
    `chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
        console.log('connected ', port);

        if (port.name === 'hi') {
            port.onMessage.addListener(this.processMessage);
        }
    });`

Comment: ...so apparently you can't edit comment after five minutes. What I wanted to change:
`chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {});` is enough in the background script. And the answer is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181734/chrome-extension-message-passing-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-could-not-establi

Comment: Is it possible to catch the Exception?

Comment: onDisconnect event (type: PortDisconnectEvent) is trigger also if there is no "update" (on extension first init)

Comment: `onDisconnect.addListener` is not going to work in MV3 because it fires every time background service worker is unloaded (after 2 minutes of inactivity)

Answer (score 23):

I would suggest accessing  `chrome.runtime.id`  as a way to tell if the extension context was invalidated or not.

```
// use null-safe operator since chrome.runtime
// is lazy inited and might return undefined
//
if (chrome.runtime?.id) {
   
}
```

Comment: this helped me avoid the error inside a mutation observer callback

Comment: Anyone that used the `onDisconnect` method but wants to migrate to MV3 where that one is broken, use this answer!

Answer (score 12):

```
if(typeof chrome.app.isInstalled!=='undefined'){
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage()
}
```

Comment: I have been looking for a solution to this problem and your answer actually worked for me, but to be honest I don't really know why. Mainly because the condition always returns false (which is a problem that a lot of people have apparently but don't know also how that can affect my case). Any chance you can develop please ?

Comment: This works in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox for me.

Comment: `chrome.app` is deprecated and should not be used, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 12):

It took me hours of reading docs, SO, chromium bug reports, to finally get all bugs fixed related to this "Reconnect to runtime after extension reloaded" issue.

This solution reinstalls the content script after the extension has been updated/reloaded and ensures that the old content script does not communicate with the invalidated runtime anymore.

Here is the whole *relevant* code:

**manifest.json**

All URLs from `content_scripts.matches` must be also included in the `permissions` array. That is required for the `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` to work.
Actually, you may drop the `content_scripts` object (as its only reason is to auto-inject content scripts) and handle *everything* in the background.js yourself (see [docs: "Inject Scripts"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#functionality)). But I kept and used it for better overview and "compatibility" reasons.

```json
{
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://example.org",
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://example.org/*"],
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that `content_scripts` is an array as well as `content_scripts[n]['js']`.

**background.js**

```js
const manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();

function installContentScript() {
  // iterate over all content_script definitions from manifest
  // and install all their js files to the corresponding hosts.
  let contentScripts = manifest.content_scripts;
  for (let i = 0; i < contentScripts.length; i++) {
    let contScript = contentScripts[i];
    chrome.tabs.query({ url: contScript.matches }, function(foundTabs) {
      for (let j = 0; j < foundTabs.length; j++) {
        let javaScripts = contScript.js;
        for (let k = 0; k < javaScripts.length; k++) {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(foundTabs[j].id, {
            file: javaScripts[k]
          });          
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(installContentScript);
```

**contentScript.js**

```js
var chromeRuntimePort = chrome.runtime.connect();
chromeRuntimePort.onDisconnect.addListener(() => {
  chromeRuntimePort = undefined;
});

// when using the port, always check if valid/connected
function postToPort(msg) {
  if (chromeRuntimePort) {
    chromeRuntimePort.postMessage(msg);
  }
}

// or
chromeRuntimePort?.postMessage('Hey, finally no errors');
```

Comment: Why you didn't use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`? can we use it or it needs to use `port.postMessage()`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your background script. Many of the old methods have been deprecated now, so I have refactored the code. For my use I'm only installing single content_script file. If need you can iterate over `chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts` array to get all .js files.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(installScript);

function installScript(details){
    // console.log('Installing content script in all tabs.');
    let params = {
        currentWindow: true
    };
    chrome.tabs.query(params, function gotTabs(tabs){
        let contentjsFile = chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts[0].js[0];
        for (let index = 0; index < tabs.length; index++) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[index].id, {
                file: contentjsFile
            },
            result => {
                const lastErr = chrome.runtime.lastError;
                if (lastErr) {
                    console.error('tab: ' + tabs[index].id + ' lastError: ' + JSON.stringify(lastErr));
                }
            })
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The top answer didn't work for me in Chrome. Instead of running when the extension is reloaded, it runs every page, even on refreshes.

Here is what I've decided to implement (tested in Chrome and Firefox). This checks if an error (the english string) is caused from extension being reloaded in development. If this is true then it disables functions from executing error-causing code across the extension via a global var. It logs all other errors.

```js
function isReloadExtErr(err) {
    if (err.toString().includes("Extension context invalidated")) {
        console.log("Extension has been reloaded, set global var");
        extensionActive = false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then inside functions which would cause errors after a refresh (those that use browser APIs)

```js
function someFunction() {
    try { 
        if (!extensionActive) return;
        /* code */ 
    } catch (err) {
        if (!isReloadExtErr(err)) console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -8):

close the browser tab and start over. Worked for me.

Comment: this was the solution for me, i'm simply testing an unpacked extension locally

Comment: OP specifically said they don't want to do that