# Why am I getting this error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." regarding <!DOCTYPE html>?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: error image]

This is the error I'am getting. It does not affect the performance of my code but the error still keeps popping up.
error: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54181734/10243797 is this your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Extension message passing: Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181734/chrome-extension-message-passing-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-could-not-establi)