# Extension context invalidated. Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am using Chrome Extension in development mode and go to the chrome://extensions page. Here I press the Reload button and try to continue using the Extension, but I see the message:

> Extension context invalidated

And I have to reload the page manually. But how I can fix it and auto reload the Extension?

Comment: Sounds like your extension has a content script. See [Sending message from a background script to a content script, then to a injected script](//stackoverflow.com/a/23895822)

Comment: Yes, looks similar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "Extension context invalidated" errors when messaging AFTER an Extension update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939205/how-to-avoid-extension-context-invalidated-errors-when-messaging-after-an-exte)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending message from a background script to a content script, then to a injected script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895377/sending-message-from-a-background-script-to-a-content-script-then-to-a-injected)