# Extension: How to resolve the errors `Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated` and `Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension, plasmo

I'm using React, Typescript, Plasmo, and MaterialUI to develop a Chrome extension.
I continued to receive the following errors even after commenting out code for the popup, background and content script, and options page:

Error 1:
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Error 2:
Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated.

Please check out the error image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7OrZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7OrZ.png)

#### What am I trying to achieve?

I need users' permission to access their microphones for audio capture. If permission is blocked but they still want to record, clicking the record button will prompt a permission modal.

##### Content.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import PermissionModal from "./components/PermissionModal";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
      if (request.action === "showPermissionModal") {
        setIsModalOpen(true);
        sendResponse({ status: "success", message: "Modal displayed" });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <PermissionModal
        open={isModalOpen}
        onClose={() => setIsModalOpen(false)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(rootElement);
const root = createRoot(rootElement);
root.render(<App />);
```

##### PermissionModal.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@mui/material/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

interface Props {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}

const PermissionModal: React.FC<Props> = ({ open, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
      aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
    >
      <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
        {"Microphone Permission Required"}
      </DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
          Microphone access is denied. Please manually enable it in your browser
          settings.
        </DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={onClose} color="primary">
          Close
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default PermissionModal;
```

##### permissions.ts

```
const requestMicrophonePermission = async (): Promise<MediaStream> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        // window.localStream = stream;
        resolve(stream);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(`You got an error: ${err}`);

        // Send message to content script to show the custom dialog
        chrome.tabs.query(
          { active: true, currentWindow: true },
          function (tabs) {
            const tab = tabs[0];
            if (tab.id != undefined) {
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                action: "showPermissionModal",
              });
            }
          }
        );

        reject(err);
      });
    console.log("Testing from permissions.ts");
  });
};

export default requestMicrophonePermission;
```

It seems that the React.jsx type error is related to mixing default exports with named exports, and the Extension context invalidated is due to the orphaned script after the Chrome extension update.
I have tried the suggestions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939205/how-to-avoid-extension-context-invalidated-errors-when-messaging-after-an-exte) to disconnect, as well as make sure all exports' syntax is correct. At this point, I don't know what else I can do. Please help!!

Comment: See [Chrome extension: How to remove orphaned script after chrom extension update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471345)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @wOxxOm! I tried adding the code for removing the orphaned content script by creating a separate content.js and adding `sendMessage` and `ensureContentScript` under `permissions.ts` where I request for microphone permission through `chrome.tabs.query` and `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. I still see the error saying `Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated.`. 

Could you point me to a working version that best utilizes the above-mentioned suggestion?

Comment: As the answer shows you need to use named functions to unregister them properly.

Comment: Interestingly, the `Uncaught Error: Extension context invalidated.` is gone for the production extension but still shows up in the dev version. Should I be worried? 

In addition, could you advise me on resolving the error `Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) ...`? Thank you very much!

Comment: 1) This error will show up when your production extension is auto-updated without restarting the browser, and this is the same thing that happens when you reload it in chrome://extensions. 2) I don't know React.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the point 1? Is it also normal to see `Extension context invalidated` keep showing up without restarting the browser? Like a bunch of them all at once?

Comment: The question I've linked explains why this error occurs (you reload the extension without unregistering the orphaned content script) and the answer shows how to handle it properly.